# Is there any way to get only specific fields where my string pattern matches?

Tags: mysql, regex

```
SELECT (match cloumn only) from mytable WHERE col1 like '%ind%' or col2 '%ind%' or col3 '%ind%';
```

This should return only the string which match with different column values (not whole record)

```
Ex col1   col2   col3
   india  hello  world
   hello  linda  world
   hello  world  melinda
```

It should return me only matched strings, not whole record

```
output:
india
linda
melinda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` to return the *first* matching column in each row:

```
SELECT (case when col1 like '%ind%' then col1
             when col2 like '%ind%' then col2
             when col3 like '%ind%' then col3
        end)
from mytable
WHERE col1 like '%ind%' or col2 '%ind%' or col3 '%ind%';
```

If you want all the values, use `union all` instead:

```
select col1 from mytable where col1 like '%ind%' union all
select col2 from mytable where col2 like '%ind%' union all
select col3 from mytable where col3 like '%ind%';
```

Comment: thanks buddy .... can u please provide me the links where i can find this type of sql statement tips